# Click functionality crashing when clicking fast

Tags: javascript, click, event-listener

I have made a card memory game, everything seems fine just that when you click cards too fast it leaves them open even if not matching.What I am trying is to get user only click two cards at a time or prevent user clicking too fast which crashes deck, also as i have few IFs and Elses (tried a counter but) placement creating issue, any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks
Full code  at https://codepen.io/ma-halepoto/pen/LJPpKz

```
function shuffle(array) {
        let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        while (currentIndex !== 0) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
    }


    window.onload = function () {
        let openedCards  =  [];
            matchedCards =  [];
            currentCard  =  [];
            previouseCard= 0 ;
            moveCount = 0 ;
            restart = document.getElementsByClassName ('restart');
            modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

            // console.log (restart); just to see if restart works
            restart[0].addEventListener ('click', function (){
                location.reload();

            })
        // console.log("It's loaded!") to check if this works
        const cards = ['fa-diamond','fa-diamond', 'fa-paper-plane-o','fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-cube', 'fa-cube', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-bicycle', 'fa-bicycle',
         'fa-bomb','fa-bomb' ]; 
        let shuffleCards = shuffle (cards);
        // console.log (shuffleCards); to check if this works
        let cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName('symbols');
        // console.log (cardElements); to check if this works
        for (i=0; i < cardElements.length; i++ ) {
            cardElements[i].className = shuffleCards[i]+ ' fa symbols';

        }

        // initialising popup 

        function popup() {
                        modal.style.display = "flex";
                        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'You did it in '+ moveCount+ ' moves'  + ' and ' + seconds+ ' seconds.';
        }

        // Closing popup by clicking x
        span.onclick = function closeX () {
                            modal.style.display = "none";
                        }

        // function close popup by clicking any where
        window.onclick = function(event) {
                            if (event.target == modal) {
                                modal.style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }

        // Stopwatch initialisation
        let stopWatch = document.getElementById ('timer');
            time = 0;
            seconds=0

        // start time
        function startTime () {
            time = setInterval ( function (){
                seconds++;
                stopWatch.innerHTML = seconds + ' s';
            }, 1000); 
        }

        // stop the time function
        function stopTime ()    {
            clearInterval (time);
        }

        let displayCards = document.getElementsByClassName ('card');       
            console.log (displayCards);

        // Click Event
        function cardClick () {
            currentCard = this;
            currentCard.removeEventListener ('click', cardClick); 
            console.log (currentCard);



            // updating move counts
            let countMoves = document.getElementById ('moves');

            moveCount++ ;
            countMoves.innerHTML= moveCount;
            console.log(countMoves);

            // star ranking;
            if ( moveCount === 20) {
                let removeStar = document.getElementById('star3');
                removeStar.style.display = 'none';
            } else if (moveCount ===30) {
                let removeStarTwo = document.getElementById ('star2');
                removeStarTwo.style.display = 'none';
                }   

            // start  stopwatch at the first click.
            if ( moveCount ===1) {
                startTime ();
            }

                currentCard.classList.add('open', 'show');


                if (previouseCard) {

                    // matching cards
                    if (currentCard.innerHTML === previouseCard.innerHTML) {
                        currentCard.classList.add('match');
                        previouseCard.classList.add('match');
                        matchedCards.push(currentCard,previouseCard);

                        // console.log ('match'); this line here for just test purpose
                        previouseCard = null ;

                        // check if won
                        if (cards.length === matchedCards.length) {

                            // stopping stopwatch 
                            stopTime();

                            // calling popup function 
                            popup ();

                        }
                    } else {
                        // when cards are not matched
                        setTimeout (function(){

                            currentCard.classList.remove ('open', 'show');  
                            previouseCard.classList.remove ('open', 'show');
                            currentCard.addEventListener ('click', cardClick);
                            previouseCard.addEventListener ('click', cardClick);
                            previouseCard = null ;

                        }, 500);

                    }


                } else {
                        previouseCard = currentCard ;   
                        openedCards.push(this); 
                    }                   
        } 

            // event listener function 
        for (i=0; i < displayCards.length; i++) {
            displayCards[i].addEventListener('click', cardClick);

        }

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting a clickFlag on `cardClick()` will prevent user clicking too fast.

1. Declare `clickFlag=true;` as global.
2. Add return condition on start of `cardClick()` function.

   ```
   if(!clickFlag){
    alert("Please wait");
    return;
   }
   ```
3. In start of `if (previouseCard) {....)`set this flag as `false` to prevent user to click.Because user here already clicked 2 cards.
4. After processing set this flag as `true`.

[My CodePen](https://codepen.io/NullPointerr/pen/RYbaPw)

**Code Snippet Here:**

```js
function shuffle(array) {
     let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

     while (currentIndex !== 0) {
         randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
         currentIndex -= 1;
         temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
         array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
         array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
     }

     return array;
 }


 window.onload = function () {
  let openedCards  =  [];
   matchedCards =  [];
   currentCard  =  [];
   previouseCard= 0 ;
   moveCount = 0 ;
   restart = document.getElementsByClassName ('restart');
   modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
   span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

   // console.log (restart); just to see if restart works
   restart[0].addEventListener ('click', function (){
    location.reload();

   })
  // console.log("It's loaded!") to check if this works
  const cards = ['fa-diamond','fa-diamond', 'fa-paper-plane-o','fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-cube', 'fa-cube', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-bicycle', 'fa-bicycle',
   'fa-bomb','fa-bomb' ]; 
  let shuffleCards = shuffle (cards);
  // console.log (shuffleCards); to check if this works
  let cardElements = document.getElementsByClassName('symbols');
  // console.log (cardElements); to check if this works
  for (i=0; i < cardElements.length; i++ ) {
   cardElements[i].className = shuffleCards[i]+ ' fa symbols';
  
  }

  // initialising popup 

  function popup() {
         modal.style.display = "flex";
         document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML = 'You did it in '+ moveCount+ ' moves'  + ' and ' + seconds+ ' seconds.';
  }

  // Closing popup by clicking x
  span.onclick = function closeX () {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }

  // function close popup by clicking any where
  window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
              modal.style.display = "none";
          }
      }

  // Stopwatch initialisation
  let stopWatch = document.getElementById ('timer');
   time = 0;
   seconds=0
  
  // start time
  function startTime () {
   time = setInterval ( function (){
    seconds++;
    stopWatch.innerHTML = seconds + ' s';
   }, 1000); 
  }

  // stop the time function
  function stopTime () {
   clearInterval (time);
  }
  
  let displayCards = document.getElementsByClassName ('card');       
   //console.log (displayCards);
var clickFlag=true;
  // Click Event
  function cardClick () {
      if(!clickFlag){
        alert("Please wait");
        return;
        }
    currentCard = this;
    currentCard.removeEventListener ('click', cardClick); 
    //console.log (currentCard);

    

    // updating move counts
    let countMoves = document.getElementById ('moves');

    moveCount++ ;
    countMoves.innerHTML= moveCount;
    //console.log(countMoves);

    // star ranking;
    if ( moveCount === 20) {
     let removeStar = document.getElementById('star3');
    removeStar.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (moveCount ===30) {
     let removeStarTwo = document.getElementById ('star2');
     removeStarTwo.style.display = 'none';
     } 

    // start  stopwatch at the first click.
    if ( moveCount ===1) {
     startTime ();
    }
     
     currentCard.classList.add('open', 'show');


     if (previouseCard) {
          clickFlag=false;
      // matching cards
      if (currentCard.innerHTML === previouseCard.innerHTML) {
       currentCard.classList.add('match');
       previouseCard.classList.add('match');
       matchedCards.push(currentCard,previouseCard);
    
       // console.log ('match'); this line here for just test purpose
       previouseCard = null ;
       
       // check if won
       if (cards.length === matchedCards.length) {
       
        // stopping stopwatch 
        stopTime();

        // calling popup function 
        popup ();
      
       }
           clickFlag=true;
      } else {
       // when cards are not matched
       setTimeout (function(){

        currentCard.classList.remove ('open', 'show'); 
        previouseCard.classList.remove ('open', 'show');
        currentCard.addEventListener ('click', cardClick);
        previouseCard.addEventListener ('click', cardClick);
        previouseCard = null ;
        clickFlag=true;
       }, 500);
      
      }
       

     } else {
       previouseCard = currentCard ; 
       openedCards.push(this); 
          clickFlag=true;
      }  
   } 
    
    // event listener function 
   for (i=0; i < displayCards.length; i++) {
   displayCards[i].addEventListener('click', cardClick);

  }
  
  }
```

```css
html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    html,
    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        background: #ffffff url('../img/geometry2.png');
        font-family: 'Coda', cursive;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    /*
     * Styles for the deck of cards
     */

    .deck {
        width: 660px;
        min-height: 680px;
        background: linear-gradient(160deg, #02ccba 0%, #aa7ecd 100%);
        padding: 32px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 12px 15px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0 0 3em;
    }

    .deck .card {
        height: 125px;
        width: 125px;
        background: #2e3d49;
        font-size: 0;
        color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
    }

    .deck .card.open {
        transform: rotateY(0);
        background: #02b3e4;
        cursor: default;
    }

    .deck .card.show {
        font-size: 33px;
    }

    .deck .card.match {
        cursor: default;
        background: #02ccba;
        font-size: 33px;
    }

    /*
     * Styles for the Score Panel
     */

    .score-panel {
        text-align: left;
        width: 345px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .score-panel .stars {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    }

    .score-panel .stars li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .score-panel .restart {
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }


    /*creating a popup*/


    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    padding-top: 100px; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    #middle {
    text-align: center;
    }

    h2 {
    color: blue;
    }


    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">

    
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="score-panel">
         <ul class="stars">
          <li id= 'star1'><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li id= 'star2' ><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li id= 'star3'><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
         </ul>

         <span id="moves">0</span> Moves
            <span id="timer">0</span> Timer

            <div class="restart">
          <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
         </div>
        </section>

        <ul class="deck">
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-leaf symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bomb symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bicycle symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o symbols"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube symbols"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <div id="middle">
                    <h2>Congratulations!</h2> 
                    <p id="p1"></p>
                    <button id='playBt' onClick ='window.location.reload()'>Play Again</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>    
     
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for that input. One question, How to precisely place a code to its correct position? I know that one has to follow the right flow but is there a way to understand the pattern or pattern flow of JS. Cheers

Comment: There are many things in this code for improvement so I think better to take the Code review::https://codereview.stackexchange.com/